# Variable values aren't available for use after image.onload?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using Canvas to perform a couple of things on an image which is loaded/drawn using `image.onload` & `context.drawImage` combo. I'm calculating the bounding size for scaling the images using a simple function which returns the values. I need those values for use at a later point in my code, but no matter what I do, I'm not able to assign the values to a variable. I'm also not able to access my Canvas's styleheight/stylewidth attributes after I assign it the calculated dimensions.

Here's a pseudos ample of my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Canvas access, context reference etc here.
    //Since I'm assigning styles to the canvas on the fly, the canvas has no ht/wdt yet

    var dimes = '';
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function(){
        //Apply original image height/width as canvas height/width 'attributes'
        //(so that I can save the original sized image)
        //Check if the image is larger than the parent container
        //Calculate bounds if not
        //Apply calculated dimensions as 'style' height/width to the canvas, so that the image fits
        dimes = scaleImage(...);

        //Works!
        console.log(dimes);

        //Rest all code
    }

    image.src = '...';

    //Blank!!!
    console.log(dimes);

    //These all blank as well!!!
    jQuery('#mycanvas').height() / width() / css('height') / css('width');
    document.getElementById(canvas).style.height / .style.width / height / width;
});
```

I need to access the calculated dimensions for a 'reset' kind of function, that resets my canvas with the drawn image to the calculated size.

Comment: Why are you checking for the CSS `height`/`width`? Don't you want the `height`/`width` properties on the `canvas` element?

Comment: Thanks! Briefly related! But my main question still remains!

Comment: Also, your `console.log(dimes);` code runs *before* the `onload` handler in which `dimes` is assigned.

Comment: How to get those values outside the onload function then?

Comment: Either: 1) *don't* (i.e., just put any code that needs to use `dimes` inside the `onload` function), or 2) define `dimes` in a higher scope (i.e., outside of your `ready` function). However, if you do option #2, understand that `dimes` still won't be set until the `onload` function runs.

Comment: Aha. So I define my reset function inside onload function?

Comment: Added an answer. If you need further clarification comment there and I'll edit with more information as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @apsillers noted, the `console.log(dimes)` code is being executed after you simply define the `image.onload()` event handler.

If you want to access `dimes` outside of `image.onload()`, you'll need to ensure it's being executed *after* the image loads... e.g. as a response to a button click.

Put the `var dimes = "";` before the `$(document).ready()` to make it a global variable.

Then if you need to access `dimes` in an event handler, it's ready for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var image = new Image();
    var dimes = "";

    image.onload = function() {
       dimes = scaleImage(...);
    };

    $(button).click(function() {
        if (dimes === "") {
           // image is not yet loaded
        } else {
            console.log(dimes);
        }
    });
});
```

Of course, `dimes` will now only be accessible inside this first `$(document).ready()` event handler.  If you add another one (which you can certainly do in jQuery), you'll need to use the `$.fn.data()` jQuery object method to store `dimes`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var image;
    $(document).data("dimes", "");   // initializes it

    image.onload = function() {
        $(document).data("dimes", scaleImage(...));
    };
});
// some other code

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myButton").click(function() {
        var dimes = $(document).data("dimes");
        if (dimes === "") {
            // image not yet loaded
        } else {
            console.log(dimes);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Generally its preferred to right all code inside ready. Hence declaring a var outside ready is usual right?

Comment: When using jQuery, you can write multiple `$(document).ready()` event handlers, each one executing sequentially.  So if you declare var dimes inside the first `$(document).ready()` event handler, it won't be accessible outside of it.  Of course, if you do everything inside one `$(document).ready()`, then you're right, it should be declared at the top of the function (but not inside the image.onload event handler).

That said, you can also use the `$(document).data()` method to store jQuery global variables:

Answer (score 2):

Your `img.onload` function can run only after the JavaScript execution thread stops being busy, i.e., after your `ready` function completes. Thus, your `console.log(dimes)` call is running before your `onload` function.

Put any code that needs to use `dimes` inside of the `onload` function. Otherwise, the code the needs to use `dimes` might run before the `onload` handler fires.

Comment: Any suggestion on where I should hook the basic image draw stuff? I mean other than ready. Say window.load?

Comment: `window.load` is appropriate if your images are `<img>` elements in the page. `window.load` fires when all elements on the page have loaded. If you want to dynamically pull in images using `new Image()`, then `window.load` is not appropriate; you should draw once your images have fired their individual `load` events. You may be interested in an image preloader, e.g., http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS

Comment: Putting it as a global variable, outside of ready works. But this is not an unusual way of doing this right? I'm pretty used to putting all my jquery code inside ready, hence asking!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/KxTny/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var dimes = 0;
    var width = 20;
    var height = 30;

    pass(dimes, width, height);

});​

function pass(dimes, width, height) { 
         alert(dimes);
         alert(height);
         alert(width);
    }
```

Comment: you will be or you are trying!

Comment: I'm trying locally on a basic example, gonna try on the real thing tomorrow!

Comment: No luck bro. Putting it as a global variable worked like a charm! Thanks man!

Comment: man see there is closed curly bracket beneath `pass(dimes, width, height);` remove it

Comment: although it was syntax error of yours because you have added an extra curly bracket in your code!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21095/discussion-between-aspiring-aqib-and-rutwick-gangurde)